# How to add dynamic change input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have problem. I use jquery to make dynamic input in php like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var count = 0;
        $("#add_btn").click(function(){
            count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                 '<tr class="records">'
                     + '<td ><div id="'+count+'">' + count + '</div></td>'
                     + '<td><select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="site' + count + '" required><option value="">Input Item</option><option value="canon">canon</option><option value="nikon">nikon</option><option value="fuji">fuji</option></select></td>'

                     + '<td><input name="codeitem' + count + '" type="text"></td>'
                     + '<td><a class="remove_item" href="#" >Delete</a>'
                     + '<input id="rows_' + count + '" name="rows[]" value="'+ count +'" type="hidden"></td>'
                 + '</tr>'
                );
            });

            $(".remove_item").live('click', function (ev) {
            if (ev.type == 'click') {
            $(this).parents(".records").fadeOut();
                    $(this).parents(".records").remove();
        }
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="id_form" action="save.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" name="add_btn" value="Add" id="add_btn">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Code Item</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="container">
      <!-- nanti rows nya muncul di sini -->
    </tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name=submit value="Save">
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Condition: If I chose canon in combo select menu, then at input codeitem show code of the item (in another case, I use PHP to get codeitem from SQL table.

At first row input field, that was success.. but, if I want add more input field with click 'add button' to entry another item (at second row input field), why first input codeitem change code item, not input codeitem at second row?

How can I input dynamic item with that condition?

Comment: What's PHP got to do with this? You should add the jQuery tag to your question. And `.live()` was deprecated in favor of `.on()` years ago.

Comment: Thank you J08691.. i used that code to add dynamic input on php, and success to add row input field, and remove (delete) row input field with .live(). Maybe i use jquery 1.7.x version. To show the code item in input field,  i use changevalue function javascript.. at first row i success, but in second row failed.. or you can tell me how cant i make dynamic input many item in single field? With change value condition? Sorry if i make you confused

Answer (score 0):

If you are not working on a legacy code base then it is batter to use latest version of Jquery.

- `'<td ><div id="'+count+'">' + count + '</div></td>'` , you can't use same `id` in multiple time, so change it to class.
- `'<td><input name="codeitem' + count + '" type="text"></td>'` ,input field name should be fixed in order to process it in your php script after form submit but as you need to get multiple value make it an array `codeitem[]`
- what is the use of `rows[]` input field?
- To input codeitem dynamically on change combo select menu, you have to use "Ajax" to get the 'codeitem' value of the selected combo menu from your database.

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tanvir86/jbua5zd3/10/) .

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#add_btn").click(function(){
        let count = $('tr.records').length+1;
        $('#container').append(
             '<tr class="records">'
                 + '<td ><div class="count">' + count + '</div></td>'
                 + '<td><select class="site form-control form-control-sm" name="site[]" required><option value="">Input Item</option><option value="canon">canon</option><option value="nikon">nikon</option><option value="fuji">fuji</option></select></td>'

                 + '<td><input class="codeitem" name="codeitem[]" type="text"></td>'
                 + '<td><a class="remove_item" href="#" >Delete</a>'
                 + '<input class="rows" name="rows[]" value="'+ count +'" type="hidden"></td>'
             + '</tr>'
            );
        });

$(document).on('click',".remove_item", function (ev) {

  $(this).parents(".records").fadeOut();
  $(this).parents(".records").remove();

  //Re-arrange the Row Serial No

  $('tr.records div.count').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text(index+1)
  });
});

$(document).on('change',".site", function (ev) {

  let site = $(this).val();
        let current = $(this).parents(".records");

  if(site!=''){
    //make an ajax call to get the corresponding CodeItem of the selected site
    /* $.ajax({
      url: "/yoururl",
      data:{"id":site},
      success: function(result){
        $(current).find('.codeitem').val(result);
      }
    }); */

  }else{
    $(current).find('.codeitem').val('');
  }


}); 
})
```

Comment: `<td ><div id="'+count+'">' + count + '</div></td>` is unique as OP is increasing `count` on every click - however an id should start with a letter